# Vuejs - Looking to call a function with data attributes from html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am looking to call a function on click of button fetching data-attribute value , As I am versed with jquery how I am looking for this to work

```
<button id="openmodal" data-user="1" data-purpose="contact form" class="btn__primary" aria-label="Help"></button>
<button id="openmodal" data-user="1" data-purpose="Opt In" class="btn__primary" aria-label="Help"></button>
```

I will need to fetch the user id and call a function, In jquery typically, I would pass values in data-attributes and fetch them and call required function. I understand I shouldn't be using data-attributes so I am looking out for the best way of doing this , there can be multiple buttons that performs different js function with different  data-purpose (attribute) So I will need to pass data-purpose and data-user to the vue component/function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy enough to bind the click events to buttons using the `@click` binding.

In order to get the `data-user` attribute during the click handler, you could use: `event.target.attributes["data-user"].value`

- `event.target` gives you the button you clicked
- `.attributes["data-user"].value` selects the attribute `data-user` and returns its value. You could similarly get the attribute `data-purpose` like `.attributes["data-purpose"].value` is you still need that.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    contactForm: function(event) {
      alert("Contact form clicked. User: " + event.target.attributes["data-user"].value);
    },
    optIn: function(event) {
      alert("Opt in clicked. User: " + event.target.attributes["data-user"].value);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button id="openmodal" data-user="1" data-purpose="contact form" class="btn__primary" aria-label="Help" @click="contactForm">Contact Form</button>
  <button id="openmodal" data-user="1" data-purpose="Opt In" class="btn__primary" aria-label="Help" @click="optIn">Opt In</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can I please further ask How can I call var function contactForm in another 
var contactModal = new Vue({
  methods: {
    triggerModal: function () {
//need to call contactForm method here
    }
  }
}

Comment: You can declare the methods object inside your `contactModal` Vue. From there, you could use `this.contactForm()` to call the method.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to call this function from Modal as well as outside the modal. For eg On Click of button I am showing a modal but before that happens I need to call a function ot check whether user is allowed to be shown that modal or not.
Now the same function needs to be called for button which is for opt in which can be used by any user.  So I am looking to create 1 function that can handle both requirement

Comment: From outside, you can call it like `app.contactForm()` or `contactModal.contactForm()` based on where the method is declared.

Comment: Posted a more detailed question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969884/vuejs-event-tracking-using-google-analytics mind checking that out?